# Recursive in php

Tags: php, recursion, treeview

Im doing a project in php CodeIgniter which has a table where all attributes_values can be kept and it is designed such that it can have its child in same tbl. the database structure is

```
fld_id   fld_value    fld_attribute_id    fld_parent_id
   1       att-1           2                      0
   2       att-2           2                      0
   3       att-1_1         2                      1
   4       att-1_2         2                      1
   5       att-1_1_1       2                      3
```

here above att-1 is the attribute value of any attribute and it has two child att-1_1 and att-1_2 with parent id 1. and att-1_1 has too its child att-1_1_1 with parent_id 3. fld_parent_id is the fld_id of the same table and denotes the child of its. Now i want to show this in tree structure like this

```
Level1    level2    level3 ..... level n
att-1
   +------att-1_1
   |         +------att-1_1_1
   +------att-1_2
att-2
```

and this tree structure can vary upto n level. the attribute values with parent id are on level one and i extracted the values from level one now i have to check the child of its and if it has further child and display its child as above. i used a helper and tired to make it recursive but it didnt happen. So how could i do it such: the code is below

```
foreach($attributes_values->result() as $attribute_values){
                if($attribute_values->fld_parent_id==0 && $attribute_values->fld_attribute_id==$attribute->fld_id){
                    echo $attribute_values->fld_value.'<br/>';
                    $children = get_children_by_par_id($attribute_values->fld_id); //helper function
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($children);
                    echo '</pre>';
                }
            }
```

and the helper code is below:

```
function get_children_by_par_id($id){ //parent id
    $children = get_children($id);
    if($children->num_rows()!=0){
        foreach($children->result() as $child){
            get_children_by_par_id($child->fld_id);
            return $child;
        }
    }
}
function get_children($id){
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->db->where('fld_parent_id',$id);
    return $CI->db->get('tbl_attribute_values');
}
```

please help me...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of recursion is an "endless" call. This can be done with a function that calls it self.

So

```
function get_children($parent_id)
{
    // database retrieve all stuff with the parent id.
    $children = Array();

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $result['children'] = get_children($result['id']);
        $children[] = $result;
    }
    return $children;
}
```

Comment: `$result['children'] = get_children($result['id])`   this error is given in this line " Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: then your response is an stdclass. so the code should change to $result->children = get_children($result->id);

Comment: The code totally didnt worked for me but the way you helped me it worked out. i did certain changes and it worked for me...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or use the SPL library built into PHP already [PHP recursive iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)